# Why does ReSharper not suggest using null propagation for both of these blocks?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, resharper

ReSharper suggests using null propagation for the "damageable" if block, but for the "forceVelocityCalculator" one there is no suggestion.

```cs
void Damage(Collider hitCollider)
{
    var damageable = hitCollider.GetComponent<IDamageable>();

    if (damageable != null)
    {
        damageable.TakeDamage(_damage);
    }
}

void Push(Collider hitCollider)
{
    var forceVelocityCalculator = hitCollider.GetComponent<ForceVelocityCalculator>();

    if (forceVelocityCalculator != null)
    {
        forceVelocityCalculator.Push(_pushForce, GameAPI.playerTransform.transform.forward);
    }
}
```

Am I missing something? I would use null propagation for both blocks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Unity offers a [blog post](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/05/16/custom-operator-should-we-keep-it/) about this topic, but a short summary follows.

Null propagation on Unity objects, which your components inherit from, is incorrect. Resharper doesn't suggest doing it and Visual Studio 2019 gives a warning about it.

Why does the suggestion occur for `IDamageable`? Because it's an interface. The IDE(code editor) doesn't know the type for an instance of this interface. It can't know that `IDamageable` inherits from `UnityEngine.Object`, so no suggestion occurs. `ForceVelocityCalculator`, however, inherits from `MonoBehaviour` or `ScriptableObject`, both of which inherit from `UnityEngine.Object`.
This is significant because Unity has customized the `==` operator. In this way, the default equality comparison you're used to is not what happens.

The blog post gives two reasons for this decision:

1. Within the Editor, Unity has its own concept of null. Uninitialized fields of a `MonoBehaviour` are given this Unity-specific null value. This, combined with a custom `==` operator, lets Unity provide additional information to you, the developer, while you develop. Instead of receiving a `NullReferenceException` and standard stack trace, you instead receive an enhanced stack trace plus some indication of which `GameObject` the problem exists for. The blog posts mentions a neat feature where they highlight the problematic `GameObject` within the Hierarchy pane.
2. Since Unity is a C/C++ engine and you write scripts in C#, you can think of your C# objects "wrapping" the C++ objects. All of the information about that GameObject (attached components, HideFlags, etc) are in the C++ object. Also, the lifetime of these C++ objects is explicitly managed. It is why you use `Object.Destroy()` instead of setting things to null. The custom `==` operator solves the scenario where a C++ object has been destroyed but the "wrapping" C# object still lives. In this case, `CSharpObject == null` returns true, even though your C# object technically is not null.

Answer (score 5):

## Probably because of how Unity has defined what comes back from `GetComponent()`

If you *really really* look at what GetComponent does, it actually *never* returns `null`, you always get an object wrapper that handles the communication between your C# code and Unity's underlying C++ code.

So when you get "null" from `GetComponent()` what you  actually get (Unity [has overridden the `==` operator](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/05/16/custom-operator-should-we-keep-it/)!) is not actually null, but an object wrapper *around* a `null`. So ReSharper doesn't know that null propagation would be helpful here (assuming, of course, that it works: because the object isn't *actually* null, just pretending to be null, the syntactic sugar might not work properly!).

Comment: But the OP's first example, with `hitCollider.GetComponent<IDamageable>()`, *does* cause R# to suggest the null-propagation operator?