# Unity C#) there is NullReferenceException when i use OnTriggerEnter and i dont know how to fix it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, null

[image: Code]
[image: Console]

this is the problem when i use OnTriggerEnter and call the function there.

Comment: i know the nullreferenceException, but i cant find how to fix this code

Comment: i think  i didn't instance but i don't know how to do..

Comment: What is the line where the error pop ? You didn't gave us the code with line number. Are you sure a `GameObject` named "GameManager" exist and contain the `GameManager` script. And current GameObject has a `ThisCard` script on it ?

Comment: **NEVER use nullpropagation (`.?`) on any type derived from `UnityEngine.Object`!** See e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58487442/why-does-resharper-not-suggest-using-null-propagation-for-both-of-these-blocks) and in particular [this Unity blog post](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/05/16/custom-operator-should-we-keep-it/) ... always use the [`bool` operator](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object-operator_Object.html) instead! And in general for this community: **Don't post images of code!**